# import of SASS partials in Angular2 components

Tags: css, angular, sass

I am using SASS for designing my website and have developed some partials in separate file say `_partials.scss`. Now I want to use these variables and mixins in my scss files of various components. So I imported this scss to `styles.scss` file which is present inside the `\src` folder. But the mixins & variables are not available to each of the component level scss files.

So, next I import these partials to each of the component scss files. This works fine. But is this a good approach to import the partials in all the component stylesheets? What can be a better solution to this?

P.S. I am using Angular CLI and webpack. Angular 2 version 2.3.0

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This **is** a good approach. Every `.scss` file in your project should know it's dependencies, that's why the `@import` is always good.

What you can improve is adding the partials to the `includePaths` (if you use node-sass), that you can directly use `@import 'partials';` instead of `@import '../../my/long/path/to/partials';` or do the styles as a single file (not component level styles).

Comment: sorry to bother you but you could do an example how to use includePaths in a ng cli project. Thanks

Comment: @smnbbrv thanks for the confirmation,a s requested by Wisher, can you please put in an example of includePaths or a reference link might also help.

Comment: hi guys, just check https://github.com/sass/node-sass and search for includePaths

Comment: I couldn't understand how to use it with cli, this might work with gulp but in ng cli i don't have a separate configuration for node-sass. Its just a import in the package.json for compile time activities.

Answer (score -1):

in style.sass you can import css / scss link.